# sudo mod probe wl not working?

Tags: ubuntu

I am new to Ubuntu and I have been trying to install the wifi components for my machine and they installed successfully. I tried sudo mod probe wl to launch those new drivers and it told me to enter my password. I did and hit enter but the blinking cursor got stuck at the line after the password line without writing my computer name again to show it was done and has been like that for hours. I even tried to close terminal and write the command again even tried to restart then do it. It is still stuck. Also my Wi-Fi options don't come up in the Wi-Fi menu at the top. Does anyone know what to do?

Comment: If you don't get an answer here you could try the [Ubutu SE](http://askubuntu.com)